# "Every time it rains I forget my umbrella." How to symbolize this statement?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic

How to symbolize the following statement?

> Every time it rains I forget my umbrella.

My Attempt:

> We can rephrase the given statement as

> For every $x$, if $x$ is when it rains then $x$ is when I forget my umbrella.

> Let us define
> \begin{align*}
> R &: \mbox{ $\ldots$ is when it rains} \\
> F &: \mbox{ $\ldots$ is when I forget my umbrella}. 
> \end{align*}

> Thus our statement can be symbolized as
> $$
> \forall x \bigl[ R(x) \rightarrow F(x) \bigr]. 
> $$

Is my solution correct?

If not, then how to proceed? What could be our universe of discourse? What should be our predicate(s)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is great. Another way to do it is in tense logic:
$$
G(\phi)\land H(\phi)
$$
with
$$
\phi\equiv r\rightarrow f.
$$
Read this as *it is always going to be the case that $\phi$ and it always has been the case that $\phi$*.
Here you have propositional variables ($r$ and $f$); and semantics consists of a timeline evry point of which validates certain propositional variables.